# Record long videos using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, webm

I created Chrome extension based on [this](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/tree/master/screen-recording). This extension can record the screen with **chrome.desktopCapture** ([link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture)) and audio with `<audio>` tag and AudioContext, using **WebRTC**. My settings:

```
mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9',
audioBitsPerSecond: 60 * 1000,
videoBitsPerSecond: 512 * 1000
```

After stop, video opens in the new tab where users can manipulate with it. As a source I using **blob** from **base64** string. Like this:

```
<video preload="auto">
    <source src="data:video/webm;codecs=vp9;base64,GkXfo59ChoEBQveBA..." type="video/webm">
</video>
```

***Problem***: I can't play video more that 3-4 minutes. It just stops. Also I can't move video backward and forward after this. In addition I can't get video duration (always `Infinity` - can get it only after full stop).

I also tried save blob as file: `src="file:///C:/[username]/video_11162016.webm"`. Or open it in VLC. Same problem. Can't move forward or backward, only play and pause.

But If I save video locally and convert it with ffmpeg or any online converter (simply from webm to webm) - video plays excellent. No lags, artifacts.

Information from ffmpeg (`ffmpeg.exe -i video.webm`):

1.) Recorded file:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'RecordRTC.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 1858x1088, SAR 1:1 DAR 929:544, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
```

2.) Converted file:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'RecordRTC_converted.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
  Duration: 00:06:12.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1262 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 1858x1088, SAR 1:1 DAR 929:544, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
```

I tried to use ffmpeg.js ([link](https://github.com/bgrins/videoconverter.js)), but I always got "Invalid data found when processing input" error.
And tried change codec to **vp8** - no results.

***Question***: how can I play recorded video without converting? Or it is necessarily?

Thanks.